# Multiplicities of conjugate roots

Tags: real-analysis, functions

If a real polynomial of degree n has a complex root, then it is clear that its conjugate is also a root. But how to verify that the multiplicities of the conjugated roots are equal?

Comment: Sure, that was missing. I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest approach is to divide out a real quadratic factor that combines the two conjugate complex roots.  Dividing the original real polynomial by the (monic) real quadratic $(x-r)(x-r')$ (where ' denotes complex conjugation) gives another real polynomial (zero remainder).  The process of pairing of complex roots with their conjugates then continues until only real roots remain.

Answer (score 4):

If the multiplicity of a complex root $\,z\,$ is $\,r\,$ then *also* its conjugate $\,\bar z\,$ has the very same multiplicity, lest when decomposing the real polynomial there will remain a complex non-real factor.

For example, and as a first step for a complete, formal proof by induction: if $\,z\in\Bbb C-\Bbb R\,$ is a root of $\,p(x)\in\Bbb R[x]\,$ , we have

$$p(x)=(x-z)^r(x-\bar z)^sq(x)\;,\;\;q(x)\in\Bbb R[x]$$

Suppose that

$$s>r\implies p(x)=(x-z)^r(x-\bar z)^r(x-z)^{s-r}q(x)$$

But $\,(x-z)^r(x-\bar z)^rq(x)\in\Bbb R[x]\,$ , whereas $\,(x-z)^{s-r}\notin\Bbb R[x]\,$ , contradiction...

Comment: Why should q automatically be a real polynomial? Is that obvious?

Comment: @Tom: Dividing a real polynomial by a real polynomial gives a real polynomial quotient (and remainder, but the remainder is zero here).

Comment: @hardmath But why can you assume that `(x-z)^r*(x-z conj)^s`  should be a real polynomial?

Comment: @Yuval.R:  DonAntonio's work only needs that $(x-z)^r (x-\overline z)^r$ is a real polynomial when $z\in \mathbb C$, not for unequal $s \gt r$. (My answer does this with one conjugate pair at a time, dividing out $(x-z)(x-\overline z)$, which is a quadratic factor that might be repeated.)